# Add input quantity to parent element and set to new element

Tags: jquery

I am trying to create functionality to take the sum of a div text and user input, and display in a new span. I cant seem to figure out the structure to get this working using a foreach for every input with the same class.

```js
$('#go').on('click', function(){
 
  $('.adjust').each(function(){
  
  var sum = 0;
  var cost = $(this).parents().eq(0).find('.cost').data('total');
  var adjust = parseInt($(this).val(), 10) || 0;
  
  $(this.parents().eq(1).find('.total').text(cost - adjust))

})
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span data-total='100' class='cost'>100</span> +
<input class='adjust'> =
<span class='total'>0</span>
<br/>
<span data-total='100' class='cost'>100</span> + 
<input class='adjust'> = 
<span class='total'>0</span>
<br/>
<span data-total='100' class='cost'>100</span> +
<input class='adjust'> = 
<span class='total'>0</span>
<br/>
<br/><br/>
<input type='button' id='go' value='Go'>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
$('#go').on('click', function(){
 
  $('.adjust').each(function(){
  
  var sum = 0;
  var cost = $(this).parents().eq(0).find('.cost').data('total');
  var adjust = parseInt($(this).val(), 10) || 0;
  
  $(this).find('.total').text(cost - adjust))

})
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span data-total='100' class='cost'>100</span> +
<input class='adjust'> =
<span class='total'>0</span>
<br/>
<span data-total='100' class='cost'>100</span> + 
<input class='adjust'> = 
<span class='total'>0</span>
<br/>
<span data-total='100' class='cost'>100</span> +
<input class='adjust'> = 
<span class='total'>0</span>
<br/>
<br/><br/>
<input type='button' id='go' value='Go'>
```